# Framework not found error with only specific bundle identifier

Tags: swift, xcode, linker, frameworks, clang

I am creating a project but I have a strange issue.

When i create a project from scratch and add pod into it. Everything is good works like as it should be.

But... When i do the same with lets say myApp -> com.myname.myApp and add Pod into it. Xcode always and always gives me an error

> ld: framework not found Pods_App_Name
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I really did all i could do like CMD + ALT + K deleting Xcode derived data and i even erase my disk and format my Mac. I don't know why Xcode gives me this error only with used bundle identifier.

I've been trying to solve this problem for weeks. Any ideas ?

Comment: I realized something that if i craete a project with special letter characters like " ö ü". But still i don't know how to install pods with special chracters

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was caused by using non-latin characters in Bundle indentifier in XCode 10.0 (10A255).

XCode replaced these when creating location for `Pods_PROJECT_NAME.framework`

I managed to fix Full paths in Project navigator by clicking on folder icon in right pane for:

- *PROJECT_NAME\Frameworks\PODS_PROJECT_NAME.framework*
- *Pods\Products\Pods_PROJECT_NAME.framework*

Unfortunately you'll have to fix second one every time you start XCode

Still I don't know how to fix app scheme in `PROJECT_FOLDER/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/__user__.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/Pods-__PROJECT_NAME__.xcscheme` file (overwritten on every XCode start) but at least I'm able to build and start app in simulator.